# Laplacian of a function implies the function cannot have max or min.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics

If $\bigtriangledown^2f = 0 $ in some region in the space, then $f$ cannot have maximum or minimum on that region.

My approach was to assume $f$ has a maximum and then use the second derivative test to obtain a contradiction. Is this a right approach? Is there an easy way to tackle this problem?

Comment: It's hard to know if your approach is right, since you didn't give any of the details.

Comment: haha i don't wanna be 'that guy' but do you want $f$ nonconstant, and the region connected :p?